# How can I dynamically call different controllers based on user role in Laravel/Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have an issue. I have a route `appointments`, and i want to show diffenrent views and backend controllers according to users role.

here's my web route code

```
Route::prefix('appointments')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', IndexController::class)->name('appointments');
});
```

IndexController:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
           return redirect()->action([Admin::class]);
        } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole('doctor')) {
            return redirect()->action([Doctoe::class]);
        } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole('user')) {
            return redirect()->action([User::class]);
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is, after login, this controllers checks user's role, and if it's user (for example), it should call User controller (Livewire Controller with view). The roles checking function is working properly, but every time i call `appointments` route i get `Action App\Http\Livewire\User\Appointment\User not defined.`

Comment: You're not showing the related files. This is a controller, not a Livewire component

Answer (score 0):

Check your `use` section in this controller class or in action class, it's seems like you forgot to import `User`

Comment: I added it, just i skipped it in here for convience.